# How to display date format in other country pattern

Tags: java, jsp, date, format, country

Good day,

I have a jsp code as follow:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="<%= new java.util.Date() %>" pattern="EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

Where by the `fmt` tag is refering to

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"       prefix="fmt" %>
```

from `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar`.

So the date display in browser will be:
`Monday, 07/11/2016 11:04:15`

I would like to ask, any way for me to display this day in other country language? For example, in Malaysia, so it will be like:
`Isnin, 07/11/2016 11:04:15`.

Additional question, is the `Monday` generate from the `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar` ? Because I search for my whole workspace, but didnt see any `Monday` in coding.

Kindly advise.

Comment: This tag library is called the JSTL. It relies on standard Java classes (DateFormat, SimpleDateFormat), and does of course support multiple locales. Google for "JSTL tutorial" or "JSTL documentation". I would also recommend to avoid using scriptlets by all means. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just change the scope to session as below

Date in France:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="fr_FR" scope="session"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="full"/> <br/>
```

Date in US:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="full" /> <br/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what is my mistake. I am passing the wrong local value. the locale value, for example "fr_FR", is already define in JSTL tag library?

Comment: I am not sure but you can set it by using <fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>